# Generate unique key to avoid overwriting in TreeMap

Tags: java, sorting, unique, treemap

I have a `TreeMap<Long, String>` that contains tuples of `<FileSize, FileName>` as I need to sort it by file sizes. The ordering works perfectly.

Now I just have the problem, that a new file, that has the same size as another one that already exists in the `Map`, would overwrite the old entry with this new file name.

I just tried to add an incrementing counter value to the `TreeMap` key, by changing the the `TreeMap` to `TreeMap<String, String>` and filling the key by `<fileSize#counter, fileName>`. Then the problem was the ordering of the keys, because a `String` e.g. `9#1` would come between `89#1` and `90#1` which is wrong, because the `fileSize` is only 9 (and therefore should came before 89 and 90)!

Then I wrote a custom `Comparator` which is able to sort it again by the `fileSize` (by removing the second part with the counter value), but then the entries are overwritten again, if the first part of the key (`fileSize`) is the same (independent of the `#counter` value).

Here is my code:

```
TreeMap<String, String> fileNamesAndSizes = new TreeMap<String, String>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Long key1 = Long.valueOf(o1.split("#")[0]);
        Long key2 = Long.valueOf(o2.split("#")[0]);

        return key1.compareTo(key2);
    }
});
```

How to get unique keys in my `TreeMap` without overwriting existing values and get a correct (ascending `fileSize`) ordering?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a composite key like "fileSize+Filename" as the TreeMap Key. This would solve all the issuse

Comment: This would also lead to the problem, that the order would not be correct (ascending order of the file size) rigth?

Comment: No. This will be handled by TreeMap itself.

Comment: But for fileSize+fileName I need to change the data type of the key to String. And Strings are ordered differently than Longs/Integers

Comment: You Make the key as string only, but ordering will be handled based on the whole composite key. Say key as "1_file1" and "2_file2", this will be sorted by treetop well.

Comment: Why don't you just put them in a class and put those in a list and use `sort()`. The `TreeMap` is a bad choice.

Comment: @D.Müller don't complicate the structure, try to find a natural way rather than manipulating data. the relation between size to fileName is basically `one to many`, so a natural way is to store in such structure. btw out of context don't fall into `XY problem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just try to store them in a such structure:

```
TreeMap<Long, Set<String>> map; //Long file Size, Set <-- file name(s)
```

now to add a new file:

```
if(!map.contains(key)){  //key the size of the file
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
 map.put(key,set);
}
map.get(key).add(set);
```

to retrive you need to go through each value entry:

```
for(Map<Long,Set<String>> entry  : map.entrySet()){

   for(String s : entry.getValue()){
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + s);
   }
}
```

Comment: Shorter way to add a new file: `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<String>()).add(set);`

Answer (score 4):

Try using a map with value as list , something like below:

```
TreeMap<String, List<String>> map; // like <FileSize, List<FileName>>
```

The above will keep the order and will save the list of **file name** with same **file size**

Comment: or you can use Guava's [TreeMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Either

- `file name` should be the unique key (`Map<String, Long>`), or
- `(file name, file size)` (`Set<Pair<String, Long>>`).

***File Name***

```
SortedMap<String, Long> fileNamesAndSizes = new TreeMap<>();
```

***Tuple (File Name, File Size)***

```
class FileInfo implements Comparable<FileInfo> {
    public final String name;
    public final long size;
    public FileInfo(String name, long size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(FileInfo other) {
        ...
    }
}
OrderedSet<FileInfo> fileNamesAndSizes = new TreeSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static int i = 1 ;
    TreeMap<String, String> fileNamesAndSizes = new TreeMap<String, String>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Long key1 = Long.valueOf(o1.split("#")[i]);
        i += 1;
        // somthing like this 
        return key1.compareTo(key2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator needs to compare both fields:

```
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String[] o1parts = o1.split("#");
        String[] o2parts = o2.split("#");
        long key1 = Long.parseLong(o1parts[0]);
        long key2 = Long.parseLong(o2parts[0]);
        int cmp = Long.compare(key1, key2);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;

        return Long.compare(Long.parseLong(o1parts[1]), Long.parseLong(o2parts[1]));
    }
```

Various preferable alternatives exist:

1. Create the string zero-padded in the first place, and then use the natural ordering of the string instead of a custom comparator
2. Instead of a string, use a class containing two longs, one being the size and the other a unique number, or a class containing the size and the name, and write the comparator appropriately using both fields
3. Use a MultiSet (e.g. from Guava or Apache)
4. Use a `TreeSet<Long, Set<String>>` and store filenames of equal length in a set (that's how MultiSets are usually implemented internally)